# One to many relationship for MERN stack with two models model one is a movie and the other is a review model

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, model, one-to-many

I am interested in creating a one too many relationship, Movie being the one and Reviews being the many. At this time they are one model, the goal is to add a review with out having to add another movie every time in order to right a review.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, "title is required."],
        minlength:[3,"title must be at least 3 characters long."],
        maxlength:[35,"title is limited to 25 characters."]
    },
    yourName:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, "Your name is requred"],
        minlength:[2, "Your name must be 2 characters or longer."],
        maxlength:[255, "Your name is limited to 25 characters or less."]
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        required:[true, "please rate this movie"],
        min:[0,"Must be 0 or greater"],
        max:[5,"5 or less"]
    },
    review: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, "Review is required."],
        minlength:[10, "Your Review must be 2 characters or longer."],
        maxlength:[600, "Your Review is limited to 25 characters or less."]
    }
},{timestamps:true})

const Movie = mongoose.model("Movie",MovieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate model for reviews and add a `ref` in it to the `Movie` it belongs to.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    review: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, "Review is required."],
        minlength:[10, "Your Review must be 2 characters or longer."],
        maxlength:[600, "Your Review is limited to 25 characters or less."]
    }

    movieId: {
         type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Movie"
    }
},{timestamps:true})

const Review= mongoose.model("Review",ReviewSchema );

module.exports = Review;
```